# How do I prevent LaTeX from padding spaces between paragraphs so that next section begins at top of next page?

Tags: latex

I have a two-column paper where space restrictions are very tight.

I just looked at my last version of the manuscript and saw that the upper half contains a figure (as expected), but in the lower half there is a lot of vertical space between paragraphs (enough to squeeze 10 more lines), and that LaTeX probably added it so that in the beginning of the next page a new numbered section will begin at the top of the page.

I know there's a way to adjust this so LaTeX doesn't try so hard, but I'm not sure how. any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The parameter that controls inter-paragraph spacing is called `\parskip`(See [Paragraph Spacing](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Paragraph_formatting#Paragraph_spacing) ). You set it (with "rubber" values) using something like:

```
 \setlength{\parskip}{1cm plus4mm minus3mm}
```

The defualt value of `\parskip` is class dependent. The "plus" and "minus" parts tell TeX how much it can adjust the value to improve the layout (that is they make the spacing elastic, thus the "rubber" designation). Reducing (or eliminating) the "plus" part of the rubber might help.

Watch out though, you can cause other layout artifacts if you constrain TeX too much.

---

Other things to think about:

- The widow and club penalties probably apply section headings, and may be affecting TeX's layout choices (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512967/how-can-one-keep-a-section-from-being-at-the-end-of-a-page-in-latex for a discussion).
- You may also want to consider messing with `\baselineskip` which controls the allowed spacing between lines of text and can also have rubber values.
- This is a common problem, and there are probably some fairly sophisticated treatments already prepared on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/).

Comment: Hey, after all these years, I hope you still answer here. I was wondering if there is a command, without changing the inter-paragraph spacing, that can tell latex it's ok to leave blank space in the bottom of the page and so, it will not spread paragraphs horizontally to cover all blanks?

Comment: `\raggedbottom` in the preamble, I think. The opposite is `\flushbottom` or somesuch.

Comment: BTW, there us a whole site for [tex.se] now.

Comment: Yes, I know, using it a lot. I just came up with this result in a search and seemed easier to comment here.

Comment: Where do you place the \setlength? in the preamble or in something else?

Comment: I answered my own question: It is in the preamble.  https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Paragraph_formatting#Paragraph_spacing

Answer (score 5):

`\vfill` before the new section worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Wouldn't that rather cause more white space overall?

Comment: It appears to work, it prevents LaTeX from trying to end the previous page at the bottom. The way to set this globally is to use `\raggedbottom` in the preamble [as mentioned in a comment to another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643635/how-do-i-prevent-latex-from-padding-spaces-between-paragraphs-so-that-next-secti#comment54449592_643688).