# How to change the spacing between paragraph on rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

**Is it possible to change the size of space between the paragraphs for the pdf output?**

I've tried to add two space at the end of line that creates single line break. However I want to adjust the exact size of that space (eg. 1.5 pt).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49188/how-to-insert-vertical-space-between-paragraphs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this `$\vspace{1.5cm}$`

Answer (score 0):

You can manually pad where required as already suggested, or you can set (globally, or locally within [a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56130565/adjust-spacing-between-text-and-chunk-output-in-a-r-markdown-pdf-document#56130850)) [`/parskip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643635/how-do-i-prevent-latex-from-padding-spaces-between-paragraphs-so-that-next-secti#643688).

Please take note the "final amount" of space should be the sum of that *and* whatever the product of [baselineskip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23944/extreme-vertical-spacing-between-lines#23955) and baselinestretch is.